# Achieving the effect of overflow: hidden without hiding scroll bars

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

Is there a way to have content hidden in the way that `overflow: hidden;` does without hiding the scroll bars? I'm trying to make a site with a video background, and to make the video still fit on the screen properly on differently sized screens or screens with different aspect ratios, I need to hide some of the video off the screen at some times. I've been doing that like so:

```
.video-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

However, I noticed that this method hides the browser scroll bars, creating a space on the right side of the browser window which only displays video that would be "under" the scroll bar (hidden off of the page by `overflow: hidden;`), but the rest of the site does not extend to that extra space. It is still possible to scroll using the mouse wheel, but the bar does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `position:absolute` try `position:fixed`

Comment: And remove overflow: hidden?

Comment: Yes remove overflow:hidden

Comment: add overflow:scroll so that scroll bar will appear

Comment: I wasn't using that because I didn't want a horizontal scroll barwhich is what happened when I used overflow:scroll.

Comment: Also, when I use the scroll bar that results from overflow:scroll, the page does not move, and when I scroll using the scroll wheel the page moves but the scroll bar does not.

Comment: Okay, let me explain you: If your document (window) is having 800px height (suppose) and your content is taking 500px then it won't show scroll bar but if your content is taking more than 800px then if will show the scroll bar. If you only wan to show a scroll bar vertical then use the following code

overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try

```
overflow : scroll;
```

or

```
overflow : visible;
```

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp